# Move current branch to a different worktree

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-worktree

I want to move my current git branch to different git worktree b/c I want to modify the read/write file permissions without effecting the file permissions of the other branches in the current worktree.

How can I move/copy my current branch to a different worktree and how can I get back to the original worktree?

Answer (score 3):

I "move" a branch to my alternate worktree like this

1. Checkout any other branch in my current tree. (the branch you want to move can not be checked out)
2. Open a git window in my alternate worktree and checkout the branch I want to "move"

That is all. I have two git windows open side by side. (my main worktree and my alternate) Its real easy to see what I'm doing.

[VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) posted a great resource
[Multiple working tree directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270193/how-can-i-have-multiple-working-directories-with-git/30185564#30185564)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

- copy current working directory
- checkout destination branch
- paste
- commit

or with ...

- git checkout **branch that you want to move**
- git rebase **destination branch**

in case of conflict, if you want to manage them :

- git checkout **branch that you want to move**
- git rebase -i **destination branch**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to and cannot "copy" branch because branches are shared between worktrees, it is there already. Probably what you meant is to checkout current branch on a different worktree. That is possible by 2 ways:

- temporary checkout current woktree to a different branch: `git checkout -b tmp` (I'm not sure how it behaves when you have uncommitted changes), then checkout that branch in another worktree, or
- use another temporary branch based on the current. It would originally be the same commit which should be enough in most cases.